# freeze top row using spreadsheetgear

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, spreadsheetgear

How can I freeze top row (and only the row) using spreadsheetgear?

when I try this:

```
worksheet.WindowInfo.FreezePanes = true;
```

It freezes both the top row and the first column (A). I only need it to freeze the top row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found out I need to select the cell first and then set the FreezePanes property:

```
worksheet.Cells[1,0].Select();
worksheet.WindowInfo.FreezePanes = true;
```

Basically what happens is it freezes rows above and columns to the left of the selected cell.

Comment: You could also use IWorksheetWindowInfo.SplitRows/SplitColumns to specify where the "splits" should occur.  In your case you would set SplitRows to 1.  Then use IWorksheetWindowInfo.FreezePanes to "freeze" the split.

Comment: Interesting, It worked that way too. I thought I tried that, but probably that was ScrollRow or I didn't set the FreezePanes property when I tried it. I actually like your solution more.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution did not work for me. Here's what I did and succeeded:

```
worksheet.WindowInfo.ScrollColumn = 0;
worksheet.WindowInfo.SplitColumns = 0;
worksheet.WindowInfo.ScrollRow = 0;
worksheet.WindowInfo.SplitRows = 1;
worksheet.WindowInfo.FreezePanes = true;
```