# R: How can you freeze the top row in an exported Excel file using R code?

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

Solution must be in R.
Related questions are providing solution for other languages. (e.g., here [freeze top row using spreadsheetgear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963370/freeze-top-row-using-spreadsheetgear))

An Excel counterpart of

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% write_csv('IneedExcelNotCSV.csv')
```

with some part of code that freezez the  top row.

Solution for similar format to .xls(x) (e.g., OpenOffice) would work too. (.sxc?)

Comment: [WriteXLS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html)'s `WriteXLS` function has a `FreezeRow` argument where you specify the number of rows to be frozen. Perhaps something like this: `mtcars %>% WriteXLS::WriteXLS('MyFile.xls', FreezeRow = 1)`.

Comment: It is _impossible_ for a csv file. csv is a text format that does not support formatting. You must use xls or xlsx.

Comment: I know it is impossible in CSV. The code is there to illustrate. I am asking for Excel counterpart and plus some code. read the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `XLSX` R package to save as .xlsx file you can add

```
 createFreezePane(sheet, 2, 1, startRow = 2, startColumn = 1)
```

and the first row is frozen.

Answer (score 1):

You can freeze panes when exporting data as an .xlsx file with the `openxlsx` package via the freezePane parameters: `firstActiveRow`, `firstActiveCol`, `firstRow`, and `firstCol`.

For example, to freeze the top row:

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(sheetname, file = filename, firstRow = TRUE) #freezes top row
write.xlsx(sheetname, file = filename, firstRow = TRUE, firstCol = TRUE) #freezes top row and first column
write.xlsx(sheetname, file = filename, firstActiveRow = 4, firstActiveCol = 3) #freezes fourth row and third column
```

Answer (score 1):

`openxlsx` also provides `freezePane()` which can be useful
in programmatic work.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- "Example"
addWorksheet(wb, sheet)
writeData(wb, sheet, x = mtcars)
freezePane(wb, sheet , firstRow = TRUE, firstCol = FALSE) # freeze first row
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Example.xlsx")
```